# Infinite redirections in mod_rewrite when redirected from http to https

Tags: regex, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite

The .htaccess file looks like below and works well at redirecting the traffic from website.com/page or website.com/page/ to index.php?site=page, and from website.com/page/subpage/ to index.php?site=page&sub=subpage.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?site=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php?site=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ index.php?site=$1&sub=$2 [QSA]
```

The problem pops up when trying to redirect the traffic from http:// to https:// with

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

I receive a message that there are too many redirects on the website, no matter what the url. Do you know what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules should be like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?site=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?site=$1&sub=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Make sure to test in a new browser to avoid old browser cache.

Comment: Hi, I just tested it with clear cache, and the same problem: website doesn't load due to too many redirects.

Comment: It is Apache/2.4.35 (Unix)

Comment: Hi, while the redirect from http to https works well, none of the redirections to the subpages work in the last two lines

Comment: It was website.com/page, website.com/page/ and website.com/page/?, none of them worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210754/discussion-between-anubhava-and-wlq).